# Cannot visualize map with geemap when using VS Code

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, mapping, geemap, visual-studio-code

I am using Jupyter notebook on VS.
I have generated script that gets an image collection, does some calculations on it and generates one image (ee.image.Image).

I want to display it on a map. When I do it, it runs, but the map never appears.

This is how I try to create the map:

```
Map = geemap.Map()
Map.addLayer(img, {}, "NDVI")
Map
```

this runs but returns nothing.  The map window is not openning.

I have installed [ipyleaflet](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/index.html) but this did not change the situation.
My end goal- being able to display interactively the image using gee map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a [problem](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/issues/1132#issuecomment-1179673334) with current version of `geemap` and `ipyleaflet` version `17.x`. I managed to reproduce the issue with `geemap==0.17.2`, and resolved it by making sure `ipyleaflet==0.16` was installed.

Using this venv, geemap worked fine for me:

```
python3 -m venv venv-geemap
source venv-geemap/bin/activate
pip3 install wheel 
pip3 install ipykernel geemap ipyleaflet==0.16 # Not working with latest ipyleaflet
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv-geemap
```

Comment: indeed it was the the version of ipyleaflet, however, I had to install ipyleafleat==0.17 (if someone has the same issue)